# How to take numbers from lines that have different length and a word appears multiple times

Tags: python, file, printing, split, numbers

I have a file that looks like this:

```
john|600
doe|300
john|1000
```

I wanted to take numbers that have different length from the lines, so I tried separating the names and these numbers using `name2, points2 = line[:-1].split('|')`, but it seems to take last 0 away from 1000. And 1000 gets printed without last zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your currently removing the last character from each line with `line[:-1]`. This slices the string up until but not including the last character. This is why you are getting `100` instead of `1000`.

Instead split on the whole `line`:

```
name2, points2 = line.split('|')
```

And the number should be stored in `points2`. You will need to use `int(points2)` if you want an `int` instead of a `str`.

Answer (score 0):

By regular expressions (python module `re`):

```
re.findall(r'\w+(?=\|)', "john|600")
```

for names, and

```
re.findall(r'(?<=\|)\d+', "john|600")
```

for numbers.